# i can not delete the right row

Tags: php, mysql

I have got 1 query under another one. I have got problem with the second delete query. I can not delete the right row. It always deletes the last row.

The first delete query is ok. it deletes the one i click.

here is the screen shot of the output.
[image]

When i delete burgers it works but when i press delete button for (32) Sauce it deletes the (34) Sauce

here is the code:

```
//////////  if we submit then delete item////
if (isset($_POST['DeleteItem'])) 
{

echo "<h1> ID: ";
echo $_POST['cartitem_id'];
echo " deleted</h1>";

mysql_query("DELETE FROM cartitem 
            WHERE cartitem_id='".$_POST['cartitem_id']."'") or die(mysql_error()); 
}


//////////  if we submit then delete justcart item in item
if (isset($_POST['DeleteCartJust'])) 
{

echo "<h1> ID: ";
echo $_POST['justcartdelete'];
echo " deleted</h1>";

mysql_query("DELETE FROM cartjust 
            WHERE cartjust_id='".$_POST['justcartdelete']."'") or die(mysql_error()); 

}

?>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5"> 
   <tr>
   <td width="300"><u>Item</u></td>
   <td align="center"><u>delete</u></td>
   </tr>
       <?
      $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cartitem WHERE ordertable_id = '$ordertable_id' ORDER BY cartitem_id ASC") or die(mysql_error());
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
       ?>
  <form action="" method="post">
  <tr>
    <td>
    <input name="cartitem_id" type="hidden" id="cartitem_id" value="<? echo $row['cartitem_id']; ?>" >
    <? echo $row['cartitem_name']; ?>
         <table>

           <?
           $result1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cartjust WHERE cartitem_id = '".$row['cartitem_id']."' ORDER BY cartjust_id ASC") or die(mysql_error());
           while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1)){
           ?>
              <tr>
            <td>(<? echo $row1['cartjust_id']; ?>) <input name="justcartdelete" type="hidden" value="<? echo $row1['cartjust_id']; ?>" ></td>
            <td><? echo $row1['cartjust_name']; ?></td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="DeleteCartJust" value="Delete"></td>
           <?
           }
           ?>
             </tr>
        </table>    
   </td>
    <td align="center" valign="top"><input type="submit" name="DeleteItem" value="Delete"></td>
    </tr>
     </form> 
  <?   
   }
?>
</table>
```

Comment: You're outputting multiple elements with the same ID, so the last one sticks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is on this line:

```
<input name="justcartdelete" type="hidden" value="<? echo $row1['cartjust_id']; ?>
```

All of the 'Sauce' share the same input name.
On POST, the last input name with "justcartdelete" is used.

Comment: @baris22 The easiest ways while staying within scope of your project would be either use only 1 delete button for the sauces, and use either radio buttons or checkboxes and go through each checkbox item checked. Otherwise you could use a JavaScript function for each Delete button to call the form with 'cartjust_id'.

Comment: thank you for your help. i made 2 forms. it is working perfect now.